# Unable to load default image in image view while getting image url from server

Tags: android, android-imageview, picasso

I am using GET method to receive some JSON data from server.One of the jsonObject is given below:

```
{
    "ID": "576",
    "id": "c1b6d2d0d946504d09a471e05d3907c9",
    "name": "Harminder Singh",
    "last_logged": "1429535277",
    "url": "common/marvel/photos/2015/04/fd64s_161_bd4c9ab730f5513206b999ec0d90d1fb",
    "extension": "jpg",
    "current_status": "icon-offline prople-offline",
    "room_id": "a7aeed74714116f3b292a982238f83d2",
    "current_user": false
}
```

I am getting image url here.Using api end point url and extension i am getting the absolute URL.

```
 String absoluteURL = api + "/" + url + "." + extension;
```

I am using this absoluteURL to load the image in imageview using Picasso library.Now my problem is that at some urls images exist and at some not .SO i am getting some of the imageview as blank.How can i verify from the received URL that an image exists there or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You really can't. But you can use a placeholder, or even a loading image. You may find [this blog post](https://futurestud.io/blog/picasso-placeholders-errors-and-fading) useful

Comment: Thanks webo80 .I followed the blog and it works for me.I simply used a single line Picasso.with(context).load(absoluteURL).error(R.drawable.default_avatar).into(img_friend); Now it is working for me .Inside error i am specifying my default image to be displayed when the url does not contain any image .

Comment: @DeepakR indeed, this is the correct view to achieve it ;)

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct way to do that but what you can do is, override onimageLoadFailed() method. on load failure you can do whatever you want.

```
Picasso.Builder builder = new Picasso.Builder(this);
        builder.listener(new Picasso.Listener(){
            @Override
            public void onImageLoadFailed(Picasso picasso, Uri uri, Exception exception){
                // your stuff
            }
        });
        builder.build().load(URL).into(imageView);
```

Or if you have some default drawable to be put everytime there is an error in fetching than you can just add

```
.error(R.mipmap.some_drawable)
```